# Multiple pinpoint command for apacite

Tags: citing, expl3, brackets, apacite

I am trying to construct a function to extend `\cite{}` in order to support multiple-pinpoint citations (still using the `apacite` package).  I am trying to have a LaTeX marked-down document which can render a tidy PDF in ShareLaTex which can also be parsed without a tangle of `\citeNP` commands inside the document

The standard syntax for `\cite{}` is:

```
\cite<preliminarytext>[pinpoint]{bibtexref1,bibtexref2,...}
```

I am trying to create this command:

```
\myapacite[pinpoint1,pinpoint2,...][additionaloptions]{bibtexref1,bibtexref2,...}
```

Where:

- If the number of comma-separated "pinpoint" parameters in `\myapacite` does not equal the number of comma-separated "bibtexref" parameters, to ignore these and insert a regular `\cite{}` command
- If the number of comma-separated "pinpoint" and "bibtexref" parameters is the same, to loop through and insert these as:

  ```
  (\citeNP[pinpoint1]{bibtexref1}; \citeNP[pinpoint2]{bibtexref2}; ...)
  ```

This is the basic layout of what I am trying to achieve, although there will be multiple TeX issues (like many, I am coming from a programming background and am only slowly picking up TeX/LaTeX).  Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

```
\documentclass[apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\NewDocumentCommand\myapacite{O{}O{}m}{%
\if\equals{\clist_count:n {#1}}{\clist_count:n {#3}}%
    \cite[#1]{#3}%
    \else%
    \if\equals{1}{\clist_count:n {#3}}%
    \cite[#1]{#3}%
        \else%
        \if\equals{2}{\clist_count:n {#3}}%
        (\citeNP[\clist_item:Nn {1} {#2}]{\clist_item:Nn {1} {#3}}; \citeNP[\clist_item:Nn {2} {#2}]{\clist_item:Nn {2} {#3}})\fi\fi\fi%
}

\begin{document}

Single cite with no pinpoints: \myapacite{goossens93}
\\
\\
Double cite with both pinpoints: \myapacite[p.123,p.456]{greenwade93,goossens93}
\\
\\
Double cite with no pinpoints: \myapacite{greenwade93,goossens93}
\\
\\
\bibliography{ testbib }
\end{document}
```

This is the `testbib.bib` file (I could not work out how to use filecontents in ShareLaTeX):

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!